# skimage.io.imsave is executed with empty file but without error

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am deskewing a tiff-image with the python lib "skimage" and try to save it back to disk. But I can not save an image with the call "skimage.io.imsave". It does not work. No errors are shown. It just write an 123.7 MB tiff-file with transparent background. If I show the rotated tiff image with skimage.io.show(), it shows me my desired result, but I can not save it.

Steps to reproduce:

- read image, rotate image, save image

Here is an small code example to reproduce it:

```
    import skimage
    def main():
        print("Start main")
       src_img_path = '/path/to/test.tiff'
       dst_img_path = '/path/to/test_rotated.tiff'
      
       sk_img = skimage.io.imread(src_img_path)
       # skimage.io.imshow(sk_img)
       # skimage.io.show()
       tmp_rotated_skimage = skimage.transform.rotate(image=sk_img, angle=10)
       # skimage.io.imshow(tmp_rotated_skimage)
       # skimage.io.show()
   
       skimage.io.imsave(dst_img_path, tmp_rotated_skimage)

    ### start program
    main()
```

If I just save my readed tiff file without changing (rotating) it the filesize grows from 3.3 MB to 15.5 MB.
Tried this short code and my other code also with an jpg and png file. Reading, showing and rotating works fine, but when I try to save them -> "TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <f8".

I check all build and run requirements from the scikit-image.org homepage [1]
[1] [https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/install.html#scientific-python-distributions](https://stackoverflow.com)

My OS is Arch (Kernel Linux 6.4.1-arch2-1 x86_64) and here are all version from the requirements list I got from pacman or yay

```
    $ pacman -Q python-scikit-image
    python-scikit-image 0.21.0-1
```

```
    Build requirements from homepage ----- my versions
    meson-python >=0.13 ----- meson-python 0.13.2-1
    wheel ----- python-wheel 0.40.0-3
    setuptools >=67 ----- python-setuptools 1:68.0.0-1
    packaging >=21 ----- python-packaging 23.1-1
    ninja ----- ninja 1.11.1-3
    Cython >=0.29.32 ----- cython 0.29.36-1
    pythran ----- python-pythran 0.13.1-2
    numpy >=1.21.1 ----- python-numpy 1.25.0-1

    Runtime requirements from homepage ----- my versions
    numpy >=1.21.1 ----- python-numpy 1.25.0-1
    scipy >=1.8 ----- python-scipy 1.11.1-1
    networkx >=2.8 ----- python-networkx 3.1-1
    pillow >=9.0.1 ----- python-pillow 10.0.0-1
    imageio >=2.27 ----- python-imageio 2.31.1-1
    tifffile >=2022.8.12 ----- python-tifffile 2023.7.4-1
    PyWavelets >=1.1.1 ----- python-pywavelets 1.4.1-1
    packaging >=21 ----- python-packaging 23.1-1
    lazy_loader >=0.2 ----- python-lazy-loader 0.3-1
```

During installation some tests failed.

```
    Successfully built scikit_image-0.21.0-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl
    ==> Starting check()...
    dist/lib/skimage/exposure/tests/test_exposure.py ...............F.............
    dist/lib/skimage/measure/tests/test_fit.py ...............F.............
    dist/lib/skimage/measure/tests/test_moments.py ...............F.............
    ========== short test summary info ==========
    FAILED dist/lib/skimage/exposure/tests/test_exposure.py::test_rescale_nan_warning[image-dtype] - ValueError: No warning raised matching:
    FAILED dist/lib/skimage/measure/tests/test_fit.py::test_ellipse_parameter_stability - AssertionError: 
    FAILED dist/lib/skimage/measure/tests/test_moments.py::test_analytical_moments_calculation[3-1-float32] - assert 0.000110473855 < 0.0001
    ========== 3 failed, 7691 passed, 12 skipped, 63 deselected, 6 warnings in 191.23s (0:03:11) ==========
```

Would be grateful for any hint. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine it is related to compression and missing codecs or your data being floating point. I would suggest sharing your TIFF (via Dropbox or Google Drive) for better support. In the meantime, you might consider installing `tifffile` package to give you a better chance of reading the file. You typically also want to look at the compression of your input file and use the same compression for output - otherwise filesizes can explode.

Comment: `python-tifffile 2023.7.10-1` and `python-imagecodecs 2023.7.10-1` are installed. Here is a[link to google drive] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1757luk0_jubHYxUjMBUowyfVtH5nFVdv) with the sample files. I can not share the original files because they are related to work. But it is the same problem with the sample files. I also tried the sample code on a windows 10 VM. Same problem. I will keep you updated, when I got new infos according to compression.

Comment: Neither of your TIFFs are compressed, the one with the short name is 4-channel RGBA at 8-bits per sample, and the one with `rb-py-sk` in its name is 4-channel RGBA with 64-bits per sample and therefore 8x bigger.

Comment: The image size does not bother me in the first place. Does the compression lets the output being buggy in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mark for the hint with the `tifffile` library. ChatCPT pushed me also in the right direction. For me worked the `data_type = 'uint8'` and one need to use `preserve_range=True` and save it with `tifffile.imwrite`.
Here is a small code example that works.

```
import skimage.io as io
from skimage.transform import rotate
import tifffile

# Path to input and output files
input_file = '/path/to/input.tiff'
output_file = '/path/to/output.tiff'    

# Load the input image
image = io.imread(input_file)

# Rotate the image by x degrees clockwise
rotated_image = rotate(image=image, angle=10, preserve_range=True)

# Define a list of data types to attempt
data_types = ['uint8', 'uint16', 'float']

# Convert the data type of the rotated image to a data_type
rotated_image = rotated_image.astype('uint8')
# io.imshow(rotated_image)
# io.show()

# Save the rotated image as a TIFF file
tifffile.imwrite(output_file, rotated_image)
```

Comment: Well done! Thank you for sharing back with the SO community.